# How to handle POST request data with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an alert button on the client side with an event listener that is trying to send data to the server. Here is my client side code:

```
alertBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/", {
      userEmail: "test",
      selectedPrice: "test",
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Here is my express code on the server:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({ requestBody: req.body });
});
```

I am trying to handle the data but the body of the request is just an empty object (`{}`).

Comment: Do you have any middleware processing the body? Give a [mre]. And please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: So, the middleware everyone is talking about is: `app.use(express.json())`? This parses the request body and enables you to send back a json response.

Answer (score 2):

When sending JSON need to set the appropriate headers, as express will only decode the body is the incoming request have the right headers see [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

But if you would like the answer upfront its

```
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/", {
      userEmail: "test",
      selectedPrice: "test",
    }, {
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
//By default axios should do this, so maybe middlewares are missing server side?
```

also as commenter stated im presuming you already set your middlewares infront of this code....

Comment: This sounds about right. Even (if) JSON is detected automatically, it's good practice to set the header anyway.

Comment: Yeah I used axios before and leaving it to guess it was a nightmare... when one developer decided to stringy the object before sending it.

IMHO the best way is use the axios create method and import the same axios instance into components so you can set sensible defaults